# Get WebDav uploading progress and status (Linux, davfs2)

Tags: linux, synchronization, webdav, davfs2

I am using WebDAV on Linux box with davfs2 1.4.6. When I copy a file to a mounted WebDAV service, it is goes rather fast, just like a regular local drive operation. And it actually is, because the file is first copied to `~/.davf2/cache` directory. But how do I know that uploading is finished and where do I see current progress? Is there a way to know that uploading failed due to lack of space or file size restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that errors are reported in dmesg/syslog. Since the operations are async, you will not get a notification (e.g. an I/O error) of a failed operation.

You could try to disable the cache - this should result in a direct WebDAV operation and maybe you get the I/O error. However, this reduces the overall performance of the mount point.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How does one disable cache in davfs2? I don't see such option in my davfs2.conf, nor `man davfs2.conf` does tell about it. You can set cache limit, but it is ignored for opened files.

Comment: Right now I tried to copy a file that exceeds file size limit to my mounted box.com account (there's 200 MB file size limit for free users), `dmesg` doesn't say anything about it, and /var/log/syslog has only messages about exceeding max cache size by open files (that is the case when the config option is ignored).